# dynamic images binding in expandable list view

Tags: android

I have to work expandable list but with dynamic image
appears in each child and am using simple cursor adapter and I don't want to save images in my database. Please How can Do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use Expandable Adapters if you want to put dynamic images for child views.

Refer the following
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html